# Makefile wont produce an O file

Tags: makefile

This is my Makefile

````
```
1.output:main.o StackLinked.o
2.g++ main.o StackLinked.o 
3.main.o:main.cpp config.h
4.g++ -c main.cpp StackLinked.cpp 
5.StackLinked.o:StackLinked.cpp StackLinked.h Stack.h 
6.g++ -c StackLinked.cpp
```
````

my output is just

```
 g++ main.o StackLinked.o
```

Comment: That doesn't look like a valid Makefile. Maybe take a moment to read about properly formatted your code samples? That will make it easier for us to differentiate real errors in your Makefile from formatting errors in your question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What do you expect this makefile to do? Do the object files (`main.o` and `StackLinked.o`) already exist? Have the prerequisites (`main.cpp`, `config.h`, `StackLinked.cpp`, etc.) been modified since the object files were last built?